# why is my nodejs app not up but docker container is running?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I tried starting a `nodejs` app with docker it gives this error message but container is up and running on port 3000 can anyone help me out?

Docker-compose script i used is here:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - ./conduit:/data/db/
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

I then stop the container to create a dockerfile because I realized jenkins couldn't executed build jobs, here is the dockerfile I wrote

**Here is my Dockerfile**:

```
# Base image
FROM node
MAINTAINER Louis Benagha
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

## Install app dependencies
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000

## run the application
CMD "start", "node ./app.js"
```

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /tmp/download && \
 curl -L https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/x86_64/docker-18.03.1-ce.tgz | tar -xz -C /tmp/download && \
 rm -rf /tmp/download/docker/dockerd && \
 mv /tmp/download/docker/docker* /usr/local/bin/ && \
 rm -rf /tmp/download && \
 groupadd -g 999 docker && \
 usermod -aG staff,docker jenkins
USER jenkins
```

then I map both volumes like so:

```
sudo docker build -t jenkins-docker .
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --name jenkins -d jenkins-docker
```

This the Error:[App crashing......](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLjqI.png)

here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "conduit-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "conduit on node",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "mongo:start": "docker run --name realworld-mongo -p 27017:27017 mongo & sleep 5",
    "start": "node ./app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon ./app.js",
    "test": "newman run ./tests/api-tests.postman.json -e ./tests/env-api-tests.postman.json",
    "stop": "lsof -ti :3000 | xargs kill",
    "mongo:stop": "docker stop realworld-mongo && docker rm realworld-mongo"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/gothinkster/productionready-node-api.git"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "1.15.0",
    "cors": "2.7.1",
    "ejs": "2.4.1",
    "errorhandler": "1.4.3",
    "express": "4.13.4",
    "express-jwt": "3.3.0",
    "express-session": "1.13.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "7.1.9",
    "method-override": "2.3.5",
    "methods": "1.1.2",
    "mongoose": "4.4.10",
    "mongoose-unique-validator": "1.0.2",
    "morgan": "1.7.0",
    "passport": "0.3.2",
    "passport-local": "1.0.0",
    "request": "2.69.0",
    "slug": "0.9.1",
    "underscore": "1.8.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "newman": "^3.8.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0"
  }
}
```

I have my GitHub repo here as well: https://github.com/ArerepadeBenagha/Mojotech_test.git

Comment: It says can't connect to the `localhost:27017`. Your mongo DB server runs on a separate container.  Try this URI, `mongodb://mongo` instead of `localhost:27017`

Comment: How are you starting the Node application?  Is the Jenkins setup important to the question, or can it be deleted?  Can you include the code that prints out `App crashing.....`, and any other error messages or exceptions it encounters?

Comment: @DavidMaze the reason i have a jenkins container is because i'm using jenkins to perform a CICD job

Comment: @Dilshan Do you mean replacing 27017:27017 in my docker-compose.yaml file to mongodb://mongo?  Because as i remember only numbers works on port, can you show me a smaple example code pls?

Comment: @louisbenagha no. The place where you connect to the mongo db database from your node js application.

Comment: @Dilshan I tried it but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're having two containers and each has its own `localhost`, so in your NodeJS container, `localhost` means `nodejs container` and in `mongo` container, `localhost` means `mongo container`, so they're different.

**To solve the issue**, you should replace `localhost:27017` or `127.0.0.1:27017` in your application to `mongo:27017`.

Comment: are you referring to the docker-compose script? because that is where i have mongodb running from and if you are, ports can only take digits as i can recall. If you can share a sample code so i can get your point i will appreciate it.

Comment: How does your software connect to mongodb? What's your database connection info?

Comment: That is my challenge my nodejs app isn’t connecting to mongodb.

Comment: I know that, as you're error shows I mean check your NodeJS codes to see where it's tryna to connect to database. Find database connection section or block in your codes

Comment: app.use(session({ secret: 'conduit', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }, resave: false, saveUninitialized: false  }));

if (!isProduction) {
  app.use(errorhandler());
}

if(isProduction){
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
} else {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/conduit');
  mongoose.set('debug', true);
}

Comment: Check your last line: **`mongodb://localhost`**

Comment: Yes i just replaced it with thismongo:27017 as @DavidMaze and Dilshan I am running the pipeline again to test the nodejs app

Comment: Good, and is it working now? Any other errors?

Comment: How do i get jenkins and mongodb on the same container and be able to build pipeline jobs with jenkins?

Comment: Did you recreate the container so your new changes would have affect?

Comment: Yes i did a docker-compose down and then start services again, went into the container to make sure app.js had changes and they do, Yet still not still working. I'm missing something.

Comment: Still getting the same error? Or it's changed?

Comment: Same error , I’m trying to setup a docker-compose for all services then use ssh container to run docker  commands that way it will be same container on the docker host

Comment: Check `/etc/mongod.conf`, its `bindIP` and add the name of container or ip.